# when does CSVWriter throws exception when csvWriter.close()?

Tags: java, exception, mockito, powermockito, csvwriter

I am trying to cover a Unit test case for an Exception.
my code looks like this

```
if (null != csvWriter) {
        try {
          csvWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception ee) {
          log.error("Error in closing csvWriter. You may loose content.");
        }
      }
```

I want to cover the exception in Mockito unit case. Is there a way?

Comment: Mockito is a mocking-framework. Do you mean to cover the possible exception throw in a JUnit Test case?

Comment: yes,  thats correct

Comment: You could try to close the writer more than once, that should throw.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your CSVWriter is a fake. Then you could make it throw an exception on calling the close method.

```java
@Test
void csvWriterThrows() throws IOException
{
    final CSVWriter csvWriter = Mockito.mock(CSVWriter.class);
    Mockito.doThrow(IOException.class).when(csvWriter).close();

    final IOException ioException = Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class, csvWriter::close);

    Assertions.assertEquals(IOException.class, ioException.getClass());
    # more assertions...
}
```